# Build an HTML table using React from arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two arrays,

```
headers=['heading1','heading2']
values=[['1','2'],['3','4']]
```

whats the best way which is scalable to get a html table

```
heading1  heading2
   1        2
   3        4
```

Comment: You might want to specify what you mean by best. Best performance, best security, best readable code, etc.

Comment: why always the best, if you do not give some code to compare.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your table using `Table` function and `EachRow` function.

```js
var headers=['heading1','heading2'];
var values=[['1','2'],['3','4']];

var Table = (props) => {
  return (
   <table className='table'>
     <thead>
       <tr>
        {props.headers.map(header => <th>{header}</th>)}
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       {props.values.map(row => <EachRow row={row} />)}
        </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

var EachRow = (props) => {
 return (
  <tr>
    {props.row.map(val => <td>{val}</td>)}
  </tr>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Table headers={headers} values={values} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='content'></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not the best way, but a simple function to do what you want using Javascript only (no jQuery):

```js
var headers=['heading1','heading2'];
var values=[['1','2'],['3','4']];
var tableString = createTable( headers, values );
document.querySelector("#table-container").innerHTML = tableString;

function createTable( headers, values ){
  if( headers.length === 0 ){
    return "";
  }
  
  var htmlString = "<table>";
  
  // add headers
  htmlString += "<thead><tr>";
  headers.forEach(function( header ){
    htmlString += "<td>"+ header +"</td>";
  });//forEach()
  htmlString += "</tr></thead>";
  
  //add rows
  values.forEach(function( row ){
    htmlString += "<tr>";
    for( var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++ ){
      htmlString += "<td>"+ row[i] +"</td>";
    }//for()
    htmlString += "</tr>";
  });//forEach()
  
  htmlString += "</table>";
  return htmlString;
}//createTable()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{ display: none !important; }
```

```html
<div id="table-container">
</div>
```